# Keystonejs get insterted id value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I am using updateItem method to save new record. 
Following is the code example :

```
var vv = new vvmodel.model();
vvmodel.updateItem(vv, obj, function (error) {
  if(error)
    console.log('error :: ', error);
});
```

This is not sending any object from which we can have inserted id record. How can we get the inserted record id ?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you pre-generate the id?

Answer (score 0):

you should use [update handler](https://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/methods/update-handler/) in keystoneJs

once `updateHandler.process` runs without error, you can access `.id` field on `vv`

```js
var vv = new vvmodel.model({
    // .... initial fields
}),

var updater = vv.getUpdateHandler(req, res, {
    errorMessage: 'There was an error creating your new model:'
});

updater.process(req.body, {
    flashErrors: true,
    logErrors: true,
    fields: 'field1, field2, field3'
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        locals.validationErrors = err.errors;
    } else {
        req.flash('success', 'Your model has been added');
        return res.redirect('/vv/detail/' + vv.id); // here you can access the id if request was successful.
    }
    next();
});
```

see more detailed example use with [sydjs site source](https://github.com/JedWatson/sydjs-site/blob/af8599aa776f46d868f6462f0e113aca9ca8089a/routes/views/createPost.js#L20)